# SLOW conversion of strings to floats in Python - ways to speed this up?

Tags: python, pandas, string, optimization, numeric

## Summary of Problem

I have a data set supplied to me which has geographic coordinates provided as strings with leading spaces and spaces between the positive/negative signs and the numbers. The data set is approximately 7000 rows, so not terribly huge, but the simple function I wrote to convert the coordinates to floats takes about 00:01:20 (1 minute, 20 seconds) per column - this is exceedingly slow! I am using Python 3.9, on a tablet (Windows 11 Home, 16 Gb of RAM, Intel Core i7 1.3 GHz) using VSCode and Jupyter Notebooks. I am bringing the data in as a Pandas DataFrame. My goal to convert the strings to numbers is accomplished with the code below, but the more columns I need to do this to, the slower it gets.

## What I've tried...

My code below shows that all I am doing is going through the DataFrame with a for loop using `iterrows()`, using `split` to break each string up around the spaces, and putting the results through an `if` loop to determine whether negative or not. Then the numeric part of the split string is converted to either a `-float` or a `float` depending on the outcome of the logic test. At that point, I re-assign the float to the entry of that row and insert it back into the DataFrame.

This works. But I think it can work faster. I have a hunch that I am employing Pandas the wrong way and bogging this down. I would like it to go faster because I will use this routine to do larger and larger data sets.

Below I lay out two functions:

> 1. `generate_string_coords` - A function to generate the types of strings I am supplied with. I'm working on a tool here, and I have no control over the raw materials (data). So this function simply generate strings that behave as my raw data do, and you can generate as many or as few as you would like using the `length` variable.
> 2. `convert_string_coords_to_floats` - A function to convert the contrived strings to floats. This is the one that is the bane of my current code; once a dataset is generated with the function described in #1, I'd like to know how to optimize the function described in #2.

Here's the rub: when I try this even with a `length=10000` (in excess of my data set), both of these functions take about 00:00:02.7 (2.7 seconds) to run! This is way faster than in my code, and I wonder if Pandas is searching through each of the 60+ members of each Series (row) of my DataFrame.

## Some Code:

#### Generate the dummy data that behaves like the coordinates supplied to me:

```py
def generate_string_coords(length):
    nums = np.random.uniform(-3, 6, (length, )).tolist()
    signs = []
    for num in nums:
        if num < 0:
            signs.append(' - ')
        else:
            signs.append(' + ')

    strings = [sign+str(abs(num))for sign, num in zip(signs, nums)]
    strings_df = pd.DataFrame(strings, columns=['coords'])
    return strings_df
```

#### Convert the dummy data from strings to floats:

```py
def convert_str_coords_to_floats(strings_df):
    for x, row in enumerate(strings_df.iterrows()):
        print(x)
        a = row[1]['coords']
        if a.split()[0] == '-':
            num_a = -float(a.split()[1])        
        else:
            num_a = float(a.split()[1])
        row[1]['coords'] = num_a
        strings_df.iloc[x] = row[1]
        
    return strings_df
```

Can anyone tell me if there is a more efficient way to do what I need?
Thank you!

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop, use `strings_df.apply()`.

Comment: `df['coords']=df['coords'].str.replace(' ','').astype(float)` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than iterating (during which printing in the loop ads useless overhead) you can use [series.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and [astype(float)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to broadcast the changes

```
%%timeit 
#after using your func to generate a 7000-row dataset
df['coords'].str.replace(' ','').astype(float)

13.2 ms ± 952 µs per loop
```

Comment: This worked very well. Infinitely faster than my code. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Remember to check for built-ins anytime you find yourself attempting to iterate over a dataframe